# backbone.js views to rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

My main goal is to remove the backbone.js views/template and implement them to rails views. What is the best way/practices to do this? As there is lots of stuff going on the backbone.js views, is there any way that i can preserve the functionality and just convert them in rails views.

Helpful if you answer contains the steps.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think is good idea to make any kind of dependency between your *server* layer and your *client* layer.

Starting from the point that the *View* concept in Backbone is nothing related to the *View* concept in Rails.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I am newbie to backbone.js
And what i want to do is: 
Application is built on backbone.js and i need to convert the app into normal rails and skip the backbone.js . 
Is there any simple way that I can use the backbone code in rails views, as i can see inside athe assets/javascripts/backbone/templates/  all templates are simple haml .

Comment: I understan know. I don't think there is a unique answer to this, everything depends on the structure and content of the actual code. I suppose you will can reuse the Backbone's templates with manual modifications. Try to move all the Backbone's templates to Rails' partials and modify somehow the dynamic code_. In the other hand I have never seen Backbone supporting _haml_ templates.. so there is something weird there, maybe they are not Backbone's templates at all.

Comment: its a rails 3.1 application, this may be the reason for haml support in assets folder!
You are correct, something weird is there :).